# How to train using neural network in python?

Tags: python, neural-network

I am in my final year Project. In my project,I will collect data from a specific road. I have choosen 5 points in that road.From each point i will collect data from GPS about which day of the week,time of the day and time Taken to reach from previous point to that point.

I want to train neural network using this data.
So,the input is which day of the week,time,source and destination & output will be the time needed to reach the destination point from the source point.

What will be easiest to complete this job in python? which library should i choose?

Comment: Check [h2o](https://www.h2o.ai/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't actually know about the conditions of you final year's project, but just a few sidenotes:

- Using 4 inputs to your perceptron layer (`weekday`, `hourofday`, `source`, `destination`) to predict one final neuron (`timedelta`), you will most likely **not** need the non-linear powers of a neural network.
- If you collect data on your own, you will most likely have too few observations to actually train a neural network. And with too few observations, it will probably overfit to your data.
- You are very likely perfectly fine with a linear regression.

If you want to try using a neural network whatsoever, take a look at [h2o](http://h2o.ai) - it offers a broad variety of machine learning / AI functionality to train models and make predictions.

However, to me it seems that you may require additional reading on this topic. You must understand how to interpret results (if any) and you should know about the pros and cons of each method - this includes knowing about data types and values being appropriate or not for certain models to be applied.

Comment: thanks....but why are you saying i should not use neural network? Suppose,the network is trained enough with data for hour of day : 3 pm,4pm,5pm ......can't the network predict time needed at 3:30pm from that source to destination?